# Responsive img inside div inside li element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an "img" inside a "div" inside an "li" element, and everything is within a "section" which represents and auto/manual slider of images. I'm trying to have a responsive images. In my case when I switch to a phone overview and resize my page my image doesn't follow it remains at the same size.

P.S: I can't change the code of my slider. it must be done as its written in the html code.

here's my html code:

```
<section id="home"  onmouseover="Stop()" onmouseout="init()">
    <ul class="slides stretch">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label class="prev" onclick="PrevSlide(1)">&#x2039;</label>
                <label id="clicker-1" class="next" onclick="NextSlide(1)">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label class="prev" onclick="PrevSlide(2)">&#x2039;</label>
                <label id="clicker-2" class="next" onclick="NextSlide(2)">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and for css here's my code:

```
/*<ul> elements*/
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

/*<li> element: Contains Image + Arrows*/
.slide-container { display: block; }

/*<div> element: Contains only Image*/
.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1264px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide  img {
width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.9; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }


input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }
```

I've already tried the CSS code but didn't work at all:

```
.slide img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

can any one suggest me another solution for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the following code.

```
.slide {
    /* ... */
    width: 1264px;
    height: 420px;
}
```

In responsive code, you can't have fixed widths like this.

**Why is it not working?** The image's `max-width: 100%` makes sure that the will never be wider than the image's parent element — in your case `.slide` — which is `1264px`.

**How do I fix this?** Without the Javascript code that runs this, I can only suggest solutions.

1. Change `width: 1264px;` to `width: 100%`.
2. Set the slideshow's aspect ratio with padding and make the image fill the parent element.

```
/*<div> element: Contains only Image*/
.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Code changed */
    height: 0;  /* Code changed */
    padding-bottom: 33.2%; /* Code added */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have a feeling, however, that the slideshow won't work if the slide is not `1264px`.

For further assistance, I would need the Javascript code that runs it and preferably a working demo of your code. You could do this by adding a link to your website or recreating your code through a JSfiddle, CodePen, or StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: Yes it kinda worked, now the image is responsive but only for width. When i resize my page it doesn't fit for height size.So to fix this i only changed in ".slide" the height into 100% and removed the "padding-bottom". Thank you so much for your help. As for a demo this is my Github site for my project if anyone wants to check it out [CAN19-Project](https://github.com/MrDronax/CAN19-Project)

Comment: Your welcome! Glad to hear that while my solution wasn't perfect, it helped you. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Happy explained, you have set a fixed width and height on your `.slide` container, which will prohibit the image from adapting to the viewport size.

In order to fix this problem, you will need to use a responsive layout coupled with units that respond to viewport size *(such as %, vw, vh)*.

As a further recommendation, consider using flexbox.
[Here is a complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a CSS responsive media query..
Something that will adjust the pages CSS(in this case size of an image) based on the size of the users browser screen?

I believe this should work. 
Note: The `max-width: 600px` is the maximum browser width which will trigger this css to be activated.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .slide {
   CSS HERE
  }
}
```

Further reading for you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Chris Happy is right.  But I'd like to elaborate more. I would like to add this to your html.  Put the `img` tag inside another div, like the one below:

```
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-container-container">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label class="prev" onclick="PrevSlide(1)">&#x2039;</label>
        <label id="clicker-1" class="next" onclick="NextSlide(1)">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Then some tweaks with some styles like below:

```
.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1264px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;    //added-line
}
.slide:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 63%;
}
.slide-container-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.nav label {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50vh;  //added-line
    height: 50vh;    //added-line
    top: 0;    //added-line
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
```

Now assuming your view has 1264 width and 420 height. That's okay. But if you want to make it responsive, you need to break this property and change it to either vh, vw, or %.  So assuming that the viewport has 425px width. This is perfect because now, you can change your `width: 1264px` to `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh`. Then you should also change the nav-label `line-height: 50vh` and `height: 50vh`, depending on what you prefer most.

Also, the technique responsive image relies on its aspect ratio. That's why I've put `.slide-container-container` for the image, and a `.slide:before`. I hope this helps.

Comment: the added "Div" element didn't work for me. the "nav.label" don't work as well in terms of responsive resizing. Also, as the guys told me in previous comments ".slide" should have a width and height unit sizes such as ( %, vw, vh)